# Get camera list stuck UI with camera entitlements on M1 with MacOS 13

Tags: xcode, camera, entitlements, macos-ventura

Create a new mac os app in Xcode 14.

Fetch camera list by these code:

NSArray *devicesIOS = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

then change the architecture to x86_64

snd add com.apple.security.device.camera to entitlements

then this code will cost 4s and UI will be stuck during next half minutes on M1 machine running MacOS 13

This causes a lot of apps stuck at starting like Zoom and Classin

How to solve this?

How to solve this problem

Comment: This only happens on M1 machine with MacOS ventura

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method that was deprecated years ago. Use [a device discovery session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevicediscoverysession) instead.

Comment: the problems still remains after updating API

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug with Apple, then.